# How can I destructure an array using ES5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Having a hard time converting this line to ES5, hopefully someone can help:

```js
function([i, o]) { return line(i.path(o)); }
```

The system we're hosting the code on obviously doesn't like destructuring the array as an argument as it's an ES6 feature, but I'm unsure how to convert it down to ES5.

Here's the entire command the line is in:

```js
const link = svg.append("g")
  .attr("stroke", colornone)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(root.leaves().flatMap(function(leaf) { return leaf.outgoing; }))
  .join("path")
  .style("mix-blend-mode", "multiply")
  .attr("d", function([i, o]) { return line(i.path(o)); }) // <----               
  .each(function(d) { d.path = this; });
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internet Explorer, functions with arrays for parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49392331/internet-explorer-functions-with-arrays-for-parameters)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post.

Comment: Good job formatting your post, but I voted down because I don't think you showed much research. The answer to your question is in the docs for array destructuring, called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace it with a single variable:

```
 function( array ) {
```

and then extract each property one by one.

```
 var i = array[0];
 var o = array[1];
```